# How to find the absolute coordinates of an object on canvas after transformations?

Tags: processing, p5.js

I have a recursive function that draws particles as a tree on the canvas. Each time it is called, I apply `rotate()` and `translate()`, call the function, and draw the particle. I now wanted to de-attach some particles randomly to have them drift away and for that, I want the absolute coordinates of the objects and push them into an array. In other words, I want to get out of all the transformations but retain the locations of the objects on the canvas.

Right now I have a solution which involves providing the rotation and location as function's arguments and doing some calculations. Here is an excerpt:

```
function particle(len, thickness, rotation = 0, location = {x: 0, y: 0}) {
    push();
    ...
    ...
    translate(0, -len);
    if (len > 3) { // <-- recursion base case
        for (var itr = -1; itr <= 1; itr += 2) {
            var rotation2 = itr * random(45);
            var len2 = len * random(0.5, 0.8);
            var x1 = len2 * cos(rotation2);
            var y1 = len2 * sin(rotation2);
            var x2 = x1 * cos(rotation) - y1 * sin(rotation);
            var y2 = x1 * sin(rotation) + y1 * cos(rotation);
            var location2 = {
                x: location.x + x2,
                y: location.y + y2
            };
            push();
            rotate(rotation2);
            particle(len2, thickness * 0.8, rotation + rotation2, location2);
            pop();
    } else {
        /** for some random chance, de-attach the particle and provide it, its absolute
            coordinates, which is the location provided as function argument */
    }
    pop();
}
```

I wondered if there is some p5 method or object that has these values stored, that I can read to avoid all these calculations. p5 is probably already doing these under the hood, so I hope to improve performance.